# Jest test files not resolving TypeScript declaration file types

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have the following directory structure:

```
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── @types
│   │   ├── foo.d.ts
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── file1.ts
│   └── file2.ts
├── tests
│   └── foo.test.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── jest.config.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

Here's an example of how foo.d.ts might look like:

```js
type Level = "INFO" | "WARNING" | "ERROR" | "FATAL";

type ErrorReport = {
  id: string;
  message: string;
  level: Level;
};
```

My tsconfig.json file looks like this:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": ["tests"]
}
```

Files in my src directory correctly find and make use of the type declarations I defined , without me explicitly importing the definition files.

```js
//index.ts

const level: Level = "INFO"; //<- Level type correctly inferred from @types/foo.d.ts
```

However, files in the test directory do not resolve types correctly.

```js
//foo.test.ts

const level: Level = "INFO"; //<- Error: Cannot find name 'Level'
```

Since my declaration files are not modules I cannot import them explicitly either. The corresponding Jest test suites are executed without errors BTW.

How may I get around this problem?

Comment: Provide your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @hoangdv
Thank you for your comment. Removing the following line in tsconfig.json solved the problem: `"exclude": ["tests"]`. However, I do not understand why excluding the test directory is preventing files in that directory from including other files. I do not have an "include" line that limits the inclusion scope. Adding my tsconfig.json file to the question for reference.